# set Timeout for background job in parse-server?

Tags: android, node.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

i'm using parse-server for my android application backend on my server.
what i want to know is that is there anyway for scheduling a background job to called after a specific time?
for example i want to delete an object after 12 hours since it's been created.
the parse docs says that background jobs will be terminated after 15 minutes and cloud code functions will be terminated after 15 seconds.
i can set an alarm manager in the client app to do that but it's not efficient and if the phone turns off or the user kills the app the alarm will go off.

so how can i create a job to delete the object after 12 hours without being terminated?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use any node background job framework for this. If you need something really lightweighted, you can go with node-schedule: https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule
Note that if your server crashes or you need to restart your server, your scheduled tasks will also not available anymore.

When you need something more reliable, you could use e.g. agenda (https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) which stores tasks in mongodb

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is parse cloud code will terminate the cloud function after 15 minutes, so i don't know what will happen to that scheduled task